# Magento2: centralize Magento 2 database for development?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

We are working on a project which consists of 4 developers. We want to sync our updates from cms, blocks, settings, product attributes, category and etc. We are planning to install a centralised MySQL database in RDS (Amazon). This works good but the connection is very slow.

We had done a lot to optimise it but still, the centralised database is very slow from local connection and it is not convenient. Do you have any suggestions how should we approach the syncing of admin data (database) across team members?